# Compact Bijective operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

I read that If X is an infinite-dimensional Banach space then every compact operator cannot be Also Bijective. But why?
I know that if dim(X) < inf then the space of compact operator is equal to the space of linear and bounded operator, but in which way this imply the thesis?

Comment: There are definitely bounded linear operators which are not compact, so your comment is wrong.

Comment: Not if the space is finite dimensional space

Comment: @maru0032 In infinite dimensions, the identity operator is not compact; there are many non-compact operators!

Comment: Yes, in infinite dimension yes, but Not in finite! But in why way this imply that cannot be exist a compact bijective operator?

Comment: @maru0032 Ah, you edited your post to correct it. But now the second sentence of your post is irrelevant--if you care about infinite dimensional spaces, knowing about finite dimensional spaces doesn't help.